# Each duplication + 15

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to export a csv and need to get a different reference for each duplication of a line, based on the field "EmployeeID". For each time it occurs, I want to do the reference +15.

For example:

```
EmployeeID | Hours Worked
1          | 8
1          | 6
2          | 8
2          | 6
2          | 2
```

The output should be:

```
EmployeeID | Hours Worked | Payment Reference
1          | 8            | 1
1          | 6            | 16
2          | 8            | 1
2          | 6            | 16
2          | 2            | 31
```

I'm not the best in SQL so if anyone can help with how to add the +15 part, I'd be very thankful!

Kind regards,
Bert

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS. It's essential for this kind of question as it will require window functions which are diffrent for each RDBMS

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select EmployeeID, HoursWorked,
       1 + 15 * (row_number() over (partition by EmployeeID order by HoursWorked desc) - 1) as PaymentReference
from t
order by  EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!